# Keep the initial iterable sorting order stable when operations on each element yield different result counts/durations

Tags: java, sorting, observable, rx-java

I can't wrap my head around how emissions are sorted after 1 emission is unpacked into multiple items. I have the following code, please allow me to functionally explain.

- Top-down content structure in database is `A` 1:n `B` 1:n `C`
- In this return logic we change the above; an `A` can have multiple `B`'s and/or `C`'s (unpacked `B`) directly underneath
- All types extend from a shared parent `Z` that implements `Comparable` with a custom `Comparator` on the overridden *compareTo* that sorts on a unique ascending int *id* per type of subclass (so this restarts at 0 for `B` and `C`)
- The *enrichB* either returns a single `B` **or** multiple `C`'s based on some type metadata
- *addChildrenToA* is simply a builder (*.with*)

```java
private Observable<A> getChildren(final A a) {
    final Observable<List<B>> bList = containerService.getBs(a)
            .toSortedList();

    final Observable<? extends List<? extends Z>> children = bList
            .flatMapIterable(items -> items)
            .flatMap(b -> enrichB(b))
            .toList();

    return Observable.zip(
            Observable.just(A),
            children,
            this::addChildrenToA);
}
```

If I remove this line:

```
.flatMap(b -> enrichB(b))
```

The *children* list will only include `B`'s since no unwrapping (in the *enrichB*-step) ever takes place. This **always** yields a stable sorted order in the returned list:

`B0`, `B1`, `B2`, `B3`, `B4`

When I enable the line, one `B` get's transformed in multiple `C`'s (one of the *items*). I would *expect* (or maybe wish) this to happen as output:

`B0`, `B1`, `B2`, `C1`, `C2`, `C3`, `B4` (B3 is unpacked)

However .. I get outputs such as:

`B0`, `B1`, `C1`, `C2`, `C3`,`B2`, `B4`

`B0`, `C1`, `C2`, `C3`, `B1`,`B2`, `B4`

`B0`, `B1`,`B2`, `B4`, `C1`, `C2`, `C3`

So the ordering "within" is preserved, but why does the ordering "overall" get unstable? My suspicion is because the *flatMap* will continue to execute operations to the *enrichB* and *toList()*-additions and since the unwrapping takes more (fluctuating) time than the other operations it gets "inserted" at random places.

1. Is my suspicion correct or am I missing something else?
2. How to control/block this flow into keeping a stable order? Preferable without something dirty as modifying model `C` to include the *id* of `B` there and changing the used `Comparator`.

Comment: did you try to use `concatMap` instead of `flatMap` ?

Comment: @BorisSafonov ... I missed that method in my inexperience, thank you so much! I upvoted your comment. If you wish to post this as an answer, be my guest and I'll gladly accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is to use [concatMap](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html) instead of `flatMap`.

```
private Observable<A> getChildren(final A a) {
final Observable<List<B>> bList = containerService.getBs(a)
        .toSortedList();

final Observable<? extends List<? extends Z>> children = bList
        .flatMapIterable(items -> items)
        .concatMap(b -> enrichB(b))
        .toList();

return Observable.zip(
        Observable.just(A),
        children,
        this::addChildrenToA);
}
```